# Get Avro record as binary array with kafka-avro-console-consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have a Kafka Producer which sends Avro records to a "test" topic. I also have a Schema Registry in which each record's schema is stored.

After that, I use the command

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic test --zookeeper localhost:2181  --from-beginning
```

to retrieve the Avro records I sent, and it returns a JSON output like this:

```
{"A":"HI","B":"HELLO","C":"HEY","D":99999,"E":90,"F":"YO"}
```

The issue now, is that I want to get the output, not in JSON format, but as an array of Bytes, following the Avro binary format.

Something like  for example:

```
[2, 65, 2, 78, 2, 78, -66, -102, 12, -76, 1, -16, 90, 0]
```

Is there any deserializer that I can use to accomplish this? I tried using

```
--value-deserializer io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

and

```
-value-deserializer org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin deserializer (actually, a Formatter) like that.

Avro console consumer uses a JSON formatter

[Regular console consumer will output UTF8 strings for the bytes](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala#L458)

You could build your own Formatter class, then add it to your Kafka Console Consumer classpath

```
--formatter <String: class>              The name of a class to use for
                                           formatting kafka messages for
                                           display. (default: kafka.tools.
                                           DefaultMessageFormatter)
```

Answer (score -1):

just do this in your connect-standalone.properties do some changes

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.avro.AvroConverter